# Reading csv file formatted as dictioary into pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

I have a csv file containing sensor data where one row is of the following format

```
1616580317.0733, {'Roll': 0.563820598084682, 'Pitch': 0.29817540218781163, 'Yaw': 60.18415650363684, 'gyroX': 0.006687641609460116, 'gyroY': -0.012394784949719908, 'gyroZ': -0.0027120113372802734, 'accX': -0.12778355181217196, 'accY': 0.24647256731987, 'accZ': 9.763526916503906}
```

Where the first column is a timestamp and the remainder is a dictionary like object containing various measured quantities.

I want to read this into a pandas array wit the columns
`["Timestamp","Roll","Pitch","Yaw","gyroX","gyroY","gyroZ","accX","accY","accZ"]`. What would be an efficient way of doing this? The file is 600MB so it's not a trivial number of lines which need to be parsed.

Comment: AFAIK pandas doesn't support such format. This is mix of csv and json formatting. You should process file programmatically.

Comment: i think  the  best way is using string- replace-regx to change the file's format

Comment: By process the file programmatically you mean edit it such that the printed dict gets expanded out into columns, like a proper csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you are getting the seconds column from.

The code below parses each row into a timestamp and dict. Then adds the timestamp to the dictionary that will eventually become a row in the dataframe.

```py
import json
import pandas as pd


def read_file(filename):
    

    chunk_size = 20000
    entries = []
    counter = 0
    
    df = pd.DataFrame()

    with open(filename, "r") as fh:
        for line in fh:
            timestamp, data_dict = line.split(",", 1)
            data_dict = json.loads(data_dict.replace("'", '"'))
            data_dict["timestamp"] = float(timestamp)
            entries.append(data_dict)
            counter += 1
            
            if counter == chunk_size:
                df = df.append(entries, ignore_index=True)
                entries = []
                counter = 0
                
        if counter != 0:
            df = df.append(entries, ignore_index=True)

                
    return df

read_file("sample.txt")
```

Comment: apologies that was a typo

Comment: Does looping through the file one line at a time scale well? This particular file is 600 some MB for data over 2 hours, I would imagine it could be even larger.

Comment: I estimated it should take about 30 seconds. List append in Python has an amortized cost of O(1). Depending on your used case that may or may not be good enough. We can find a faster solution if required. If you are in control of the data generating process I would recommend that you eschew he dictionary and just make a flat CSV. As it currently stands the file is not a valid CSV and the dictionary is not valid JSON.

Comment: So I've tried it and vs code crashed. Unfortunately I am not in control of the data generation, I wish that was the case though :)

Comment: How did it crash? What error did you get?

Comment: No error just "Killed" writing in the terminal. Apparently a common cause for this is attempting to allocate too much memory, I tried reading the file line by line and instead of appending to an array, writing into another file isntead, this seemed to work

Comment: That is to say, writing into another file in "CSV" format such that I can pd.read_csv the new file

Comment: Good to hear. Hope you found the solution/discussion useful.

Comment: why not convert the above to a generator, that way you save memory

Comment: @Ade_1 I think there is no need for a generator here but you are right that reading lines one by should save a significant amount of memory. I've updated the solution to use readline() instead.

More memory could be saved using a generator and appending to the DataFrame but you would need to chunk it to avoid too many calls to the pandas append functino which is O(n). I think it would complicate things too much.

Comment: @Ade_1 I bit the bullet and just chunked the reading. Could you try the new solution and accept the answer if it works for you. You can adapt the chunk_size to control how much memory is being allocated while reading.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should convert your csv file to json format and then look at this site on how to transform the dictionary into a pandas dataframe : [https://www.delftstack.com/fr/howto/python-pandas/how-to-convert-python-dictionary-to-pandas-dataframe/#:~:text=2%20banana%2012-,M%C3%A9thode%20pandas.,le%20nom%20de%20la%20colonne](https://www.delftstack.com/fr/howto/python-pandas/how-to-convert-python-dictionary-to-pandas-dataframe/#:%7E:text=2%20banana%2012-,M%C3%A9thode%20pandas.,le%20nom%20de%20la%20colonne).

Comment: Json file format would be having the entire csv written like `{'timestamp': 1616580317.0733, 'Roll': 0.563820598084682, 'Pitch': 0.29817540218781163, 'Yaw': 60.18415650363684, 'gyroX': 0.006687641609460116, 'gyroY': -0.012394784949719908, 'gyroZ': -0.0027120113372802734, 'accX': -0.12778355181217196, 'accY': 0.24647256731987, 'accZ': 9.763526916503906}` right?

Comment: Yes, but it seems to me that if you have several dictionaries, they must be encapsulated in another dictionary. I could be wrong.